# Replacing 15.6" HP FHD Laptop display panel with HD? (Or alternate source for replacement)

Tags: laptop, laptop-display

My HP Pavilion 15's FHD display panel stopped working, and I had a mind to order a replacement part and swap it out. Unfortunately, the replacement part (#764623-001) is listed at >$800 on the HP parts store. However, the HD version (#762513-001) is listed at only $123. For context, my (rather beefy) laptop, as a whole, cost ~$900. Would it be possible to replace the FHD panel with an HD one without too much hassle? Or, preferably, is there a way to obtain the FHD panel at a reasonable price?

And yes, I am sure it's the panel. I've already replaced the display cable, to no avail.

Edit: Have already found source for replacement. However, please don't disregard my question on downgrading resolution, as it may be useful for others/future reference.

Comment: Someone would need to locate and consult the technical and service manuals to figure out if it is plug-compatible.  It would be easier to just contact HP tech support and ask them (or even HP sales).

Answer (score -1):

I tried the opposite... ANd it didn't work beside the conector seems to be the same the screen shows backlight... But it never shows any image.

The plug switch exactly the same, but maybe it's a GPU issue, in this case you have luck and for sure you won't have the same problem.